# Naming Conglomerate Company

Tags: word-choice, business-language

I am looking to name a Canadian corporation that is the holding corporation for a group of companies, a conglomerate. I am wondering whether to include the word "the" in the company name.

For example, would you use:

The Smith Group Inc.

or

Smith Group Inc.

Comment: The in my opinion sounds arrogant. Just an opinion.

Comment: Large conglomerates that need names hire professional company-namers (they need to for copyright reasons), who generally don't ask how to perform their job on stackexchange sites.

Comment: @PeterShor, its true that conglomerates use professional company-namers (or "brand identity consultants"), but it has a lot more to do with trademark law than copyrights.

Comment: Include it if you like how it looks and sounds, otherwise, don't.

Answer (score 1):

'The Smith', evokes in my memory the poem by Longfellow. If you want your company to be regarded as big, mighty and strong, what better name could you call it?

Under a spreading chestnut-tree
The village smithy stands;
**The smith**, a mighty man is he,
With large and sinewy hands;
And the muscles of his brawny arms
Are strong as iron bands.

His hair is crisp, and black, and long,
His face is like the tan;
His brow is wet with honest sweat,
He earns whate'er he can,
And looks the whole world in the face,
For he owes not any man.

Week in, week out, from morn till night,
You can hear his bellows blow;
You can hear him swing his heavy sledge,
With measured beat and slow,
Like a sexton ringing the village bell,
When the evening sun is low.

And children coming home from school
Look in at the open door;
They love to see the flaming forge,
And hear the bellows roar,
And catch the burning sparks that fly
Like chaff from a threshing-floor.

He goes on Sunday to the church,
And sits among his boys;
He hears the parson pray and preach,
He hears his daughter's voice,
Singing in the village choir,
And it makes his heart rejoice.

It sounds to him like her mother's voice,
Singing in Paradise!
He needs must think of her once more,
How in the grave she lies;
And with his hard, rough hand he wipes
A tear out of his eyes.

Toiling,--rejoicing,--sorrowing,
Onward through life he goes;
Each morning sees some task begin,
Each evening sees it close
Something attempted, something done,
Has earned a night's repose.

Thanks, thanks to thee, my worthy friend,
For the lesson thou hast taught!
Thus at the flaming forge of life
Our fortunes must be wrought;
Thus on its sounding anvil shaped
Each burning deed and thought.